# How to change count after each mapped item in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am having trouble implementing this correctly with React, I will try and explain this the best I can.

Here I have a static array of numbers that hold 3 different numbers that I need to apply to my mapped component(**OtherComponent**). This code directly bellow works, but I think I am using count(**heightCount**) and my static array(**lineSegmentHeights**) wrong within React.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { OtherCompnonent } from "./OtherComponent";

export const FuncComponent: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const lineSegmentHeights: number[] = [139, 88, 38];
  let heightCount: number = 0;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {props.data.map((item, index) => {
        if (heightCount >= 3) {
          heightCount = 0;
        }
        heightCount++;

        return (
          <OtherComponent
            key={`${index - test}`}
            compData={item}
            lineSegmentHeight={
              lineSegmentHeight[minorMilestonesHeightCount - 1]
            }
          />
        );
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

I then tried this to monitor count with `useState`:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { OtherCompnonent } from "./OtherComponent";

export const FuncComponent: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const lineSegmentHeights: number[] = [139, 88, 38];
  const [heightCount, setHeightCount] = useState <number> 0;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {props.data.map((item, index) => {
        if (heightCount >= 3) {
          heightCount(0);
        }
        setHeightCount(heightCount + 1);

        return (
          <OtherComponent
            key={`${index - test}`}
            compData={item}
            lineSegmentHeight={lineSegmentHeight[heightCount - 1]}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Which causes a lot of life cycle render errors.

My main questions are how should I correctly store this array of static values that will never change? Also how do I  correctly monitor the count with react so that the first mapped component gets a `lineSegmentHeight === 139`, the next one gets `lineSegmentHeight === 88`, next one gets `38`, next one gets `139`, next one gets `88`.... etc.

Please let me know if I can explain anything further or better, thank you so much for your time. Any help is welcome. Happy Coding!

Comment: I don't get this part:  ` heightCount(0);`

Comment: @wentjun I set the count back to 0 because we hit the end of the lineSemnentHeight array.

Comment: To set the count back to 0 you want to `setHeightCount(0)`